# PageTransformer with LoopViewPager blank page

Tags: android, android-viewpager, infinite-loop, android-pagetransformer

I'm using custom **LoopViewPager** with [DepthPageTransformer](https://github.com/ToxicBakery/ViewPagerTransforms) and it's looping good but showing blank page. View Pager Looping.

***Example Video:***
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Detxj.gif